# adding tree elements into a new list recursively-java

Tags: java, list, recursion, binary-search-tree

How would you recursively add all the elements of a polymorphic tree into a list? And how would you traverse through an entire polymorphic tree?

Comment: first you choose how you want to traverse through your tree. E.g [depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_2) or [breadth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_2). Try to understand the examples in the wikipedia links and you will have a good idea how to implement the traversal. Afterwards putting the elements into a list is a simple `list.add(element)` with an `ArrayList` for example. There the polymorphism comes into play. If you really want *all* possible Types in the list, you could use `ArrayList<Object>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to traverse though the tree. These two traversals are depth-first and breadth first. [This](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/dfs-vs-bfs/) shows the basics of how each traversal works.
The basics are:

```
depth-first: 
Visit the starting vertex
Proceed as far as possible along a given path (via a neighbor) before “backtracking” and going along the next path

breadth-first:
visit the starting vertex
visit all of its neighbors
visit all unvisited vertices 2 edges away
visit all unvisited vertices 3 edges away, etc
```

Each run time is:

```
Let V = number of vertices in the graph, and E = number of edges

A traversal requires O(V + E) steps.
for a dense graph, E->V2, so the worst-case bound is  O(V2)
for a sparse graph, O(V + E) << O(V2)
```

In your recursive traversal code, you could add each node to a list/hash map to store the information.